# DateTime DayOfWeek Comparison

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Id like to Compare a date to see if it is before Saturday like so:

```
        //Check if Saturday YET
        if (MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek < DateTime.DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            IGottaWork();
        else
            Party();
```

There seems to be no way to do this.

Is there a way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not cast to int and compare?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not this?

```
    if (MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
          && MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
    {
        IGottaWork();
    }
    else
        Party();
```

Or even better:

```
List<DayOfWeek> partyDays = new List<DayOfWeek> {
    DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday
};

if (partyDays.Contains(MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek))
    Party();
else
    IGottaWork();
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I don't need DateTime before the DayOfWeek. Silly me :)

Thanks for the help

Comment: I just posted on my blog (didn't seem appropriate as an answer here) two of my favorite custom extension methods In and Between. Sometimes I think I spend too much time trying to make my code look like a document. http://www.josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/in-between

Comment: That's weird... in the edit history it shows me editing the DayOfWeek stuff... all I did in my edit was change || to &&.

Comment: @Josh - That is because I edited my answer to remove them just before you edited my logic error.  A perfect storm of edits! :)

Comment: If you are interested on a faster way to retrieve the day of the week:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22278311/3315914

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN:

> The value of the constants in the DayOfWeek enumeration ranges from
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday to DayOfWeek.Saturday. If cast to an integer, its
>   value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six
>   (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

So you can also use greater than and less than operators for your calculation.

```
//Check if Saturday YET
if (MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Saturday && MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    IGottaWork();
else
    Party();
```

Answer (score 1):

DayOfWeek is an enum starting with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as the last element hence 6 in integer terms. Think of that when comparing.

Answer (score 1):

If you would rather do comparisons rather than checking a list, you could also do this:

```
if ((MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek.CompareTo(DayOfWeek.Sunday) > 0) && (MYWorkDay.DayOfWeek.CompareTo(DayOfWeek.Saturday) < 0))
{
      IGottaWork();
}
else
{
      Party();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (new [] {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}.Contains(d.DayOfWeek)) {
  // party :D
} else {
  // work  D:
}
```